# How to force an oAuth token renewal (access-token + refresh token) with Spring boot keycloak adapter + spring security.?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I have a multi-tenant application (springboot keycloak adapter + spring security) secured by Keycloak. Given the multi-tenant nature of the project, I wrote a multi-client connector which works fine.

On the official Keycloak doc, it is recommended (for multi-tenant applications) to model each tenant as a new realm, but for me it works better to have multiple clients within the same same realm. This is due to following advantages:

- Client scopes, groups and other configs can be shared
- Users don't need to be duplicated on N different realms
- SSO login works perfectly within same realm clients (by using bearer
  services +CORS)

So, everything works fine except for 1 thing, my initial SSO `access_token` (which is then shared across all bearer-only services by means of CORS) is kind of big (it shows all the resources - tenants - and its roles within each resource/tenant).

I'd like to limit the size of the `access_token`, by means of using "scopes" to restrict the roles in the token to only those meaningful to the tenant where I'm logged in at that time. For this, I'm manually firing a Request to the auth server (outside of the standard functionality provided by springboot/spring security) with the goal of manually overwriting whatever access-token exists within my app, with the new one generated by my extra request.

My "new" token request looks similar to this:

```
    SimpleKeycloakAccount currentUserAccount = (SimpleKeycloakAccount) auth.getDetails();
            String authServerUrl = currentUserAccount.getKeycloakSecurityContext().getDeployment().getAuthServerBaseUrl();
            String realm = currentUserAccount.getKeycloakSecurityContext().getDeployment().getRealm();
            String resource =  currentUserAccount.getKeycloakSecurityContext().getDeployment().getResourceName();
            String refreshToken = currentUserAccount.getKeycloakSecurityContext().getRefreshToken();
            String token = currentUserAccount.getKeycloakSecurityContext().getTokenString();
            
            
            Http http = new Http( new Configuration(authServerUrl, realm, resource,
                            currentUserAccount.getKeycloakSecurityContext().getDeployment().getResourceCredentials()
                           , null), 
                       (params, headers) -> {});
            
            String url = authServerUrl + "/realms/" + realm + "/protocol/openid-connect/token";
            
            AccessTokenResponse response = http.<AccessTokenResponse>post(url)
                .authentication()
                    .client()
                .form()
                    .param("grant_type", "refresh_token")
                    .param("refresh_token", refreshToken)
                    .param("client_id", resource)
                    .param("client_secret", "SOME_SECRET")
                    .param("scope", "SOME_SCOPE_TO_RESTRICT_ROLES")
                .response()
                    .json(AccessTokenResponse.class)
                .execute();

// :) -  response.getToken() and response.getRefreshToken(), contain new successfully generated tokens
```

My question is, how can I force my-app to change/reset the standard access-token & refresh_token obtained by the usual means, with these "custom created" tokens? or is that possible at all?

Thx for any feedback!

**Further Information**

To clarify more, lets analyze the behavior of a typical springboot/spring security project integrated with Keycloak:

- You protect your endpoints with "roles" via configurations (either on the application.properties, or on the SecurityContext)
- You know that this Spring application talks in the back channel with the Keycloak authorization server, that's how you become the access_token (But all this is a black box for the developer, you only know a Principal was created, a Security Context, Credentials; etc - everything happens behind the curtains)

Considering those 2 points above, imagine that you use an Http library to basically request a new token towards the auth server token endpoint like in the code above (yes filtered by scopes and everything). So the situation now is that though you have created a valid `access_token` (and `refresh_token`); since they were created "manually" by firing a request towards the token endpoint, this new token hasn't been "incorporated" to the application because No new Principal has been created, no new security context has been generated, etc. In other words, to the springboot application this new token is non-existent.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to tell sprinboot/spring security: "Hey pal, I know you didn't generate this token yourself, but please accept it and behave as if you'd have created it".

I hope this clarifies the intent of my question.

Comment: Wouldn't this happen automatically at the first request since the token your client app has is now invalid?

Comment: The original token doesn't become invalid by issuing a new token-request. No, the application is completely ignoring the new the token, and will only refresh as it would in any other app, when it become invalid after 5 mins (usually 5 mins).

Comment: @Eugen Covaci Lets say you have a valid token, and then you "refresh it",  that doesn't invalidate the original one. The original one is invalidated when it expires or is explitly revoqued.

Comment: @tony_008 How do you determine the tenant at login? Where is this information stored in keycloak?

Comment: @Boomer, each tennant is just a standard keycloak client. I have a "main backend" wich is also a Keycloack client. through token metadata I receive the tennants where the user exist. From there bearer-only "multitennant endpoints", need  custom multitennat connectors this is not provided out of the box. Specifically you'll want to  extend "KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver implements KeycloakConfigResolver" where the method "createDeploymentJSON(AccessToken accessToken, String tennantNo)" can be parametrized to use different configs; and also on the SecurityConfig  "KeycloakConfigResolver"

Comment: public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver()  method, will return our custom: "public class MultiTenantBearerTokenConfigResolver extends KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver implements KeycloakConfigResolver"..... Reading it doesn't make it very clear sorry. But you basically need a way to load different Deployments instead of the hardcoded one that you can usually specify through your application.properties/ SecurityConfig. The Idea of a multitennant connector is what they suggest on the official documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give some closure to this question:

1. No, there doesn't seem to be any elegant or intended way to force a manual token renewal by means of using springboot/spring security keycloak connector.
2. The Javascript connector can do this trivially like this:

   ```
    // for creating your keycloak connector
    var keycloak = Keycloak({
                   url: 'http://localhost:8080/auth',
                   realm: '[YOUR_REALM]',
                   clientId: '[YOUR_CLIENT]'
               });


    // for login in (change scopes list to change access capabilities)
    var options = {
          scope: [EMPTY_STRING_SEPARATED_LIST_OF_SCOPES]  // <-- here specify valid scopes
        };

    keycloak.login(options); // <-- receive a new token with correctly processed scopes
   ```
3. Given how easy it is to do this with the Keycloak client JS adapter, and how obscure it is to do this with the springboot/spring security adapter, it follows following:
   Security design seems intended to have 2 (Keycloak security) layers; the first is a front-facing public client (usually password protected), and the 2nd layer is composed of several bearer-only services which would ussually only accept acces-tokens. If for those bearer-only services you want to implement finner grained control via scopes, you achieve that trivially by using a javascript based Keycloak client (other connectors as explained won't deal nicely with the header modification necessary to deal with OAuth2 scopes).

Answer (score 0):

You can revoke a token using `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.ConsumerTokenServices#revokeToken` method.

On the Autorization Server:

```
@Resource(name="tokenServices")
ConsumerTokenServices tokenServices;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/tokens/revoke/{tokenId:.*}")
@ResponseBody
public String revokeToken(@PathVariable String tokenId) {
    tokenServices.revokeToken(tokenId);
    return tokenId;
}
```

Of course, you'll have to secure this method since is a very sensitive one.

Comment: thx for your comment @Eugen CovaciI :). I don't really need the original token revoqued, what I need is that the token which was "artifitially created" (that is outside of the standard springboot/keycloak integration) to be regarded as the new  access_token (because it contains the new tennat roles). Even if the old token is invalidated, the app will replace it with another token which is not the one that I created. I'd be great if I could replace the original access_token with a custom created one (and not the typical one which spring security requests bc that one lacks the necessary scopes).

Answer (score 0):

In the case that each tenant is a separate client you can just use keycloak's "Scope" mapping at each client. Just turn off **Full Scope Allowed** and your tokens will only contain the user's roles for that specific client (tenant).

"Scope Mappings" is a a non intuitive way of saying "Define what roles should go into the access token" :-)

When turned off the UI changes and you even can configure what other roles of other clients should additionally go into the access token.

[image: Reducing scope mapping of a client]

Comment: Thx for the suggestion. Actually scope mapping is something I've used before. The only problem here, is that since I'm using CORS for token sharing, I've only 2 options: either I load all roles of all Tennant's in the token which is working now but I'm trying to avoid. Or (similar to your recommendation) filter the roles by some Tennant's scope, so that the created token is limited to the Tennant. In trying to achieve this, I'm explicitly requesting the auth server for a token limited to that Tennant's scope (which works), but I still need spring security to use this new token .

Comment: Basically what u mention is what I'm trying to accomplish. I create a new token with roles limited by the scope to that Tennant - which is successfuly created, but I haven't been able to tell "spring security" to use that new token, it keeps using the old token.

Comment: since the space is kind of limited here, I edited the original post with a "Further Information" section to explain more clearly my problem. Thanks for your support :).